# How To Use gearman client in MySQL Trigger implementation

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, gearman

I have set up [gearman udf  for database](http://gearman.org/download/#databases) and trying to send a gearman job from mysql query. Normally it is just working fine. as conventional call from mysql query is as follows:

```
SELECT gman_do_background("eventName", "data");
```

Now the problem is happening when I am trying to give this call from a mysql trigger implementation. An error is showing up as follows:

```
MySQL said: #1415 - Not allowed to return a result set from a trigger
```

So, basically as you can see, either

1. There is some other way for the gearman call or
2. Somehow I have make a fake update call with the gearman select call inside there.

I am trying to write the Trigger which is pretty much simple as below:

```
BEGIN
    SELECT gman_do_background("eventName", "@data") FROM 
    (
         SELECT @data := CONCAT(a,',',b,',',c) FROM mytablename WHERE status = 1
    )
END
```

but as yo can see, because of the 'SELECT' operation, its not saving and throwing the above error.

Can anyone please help me whether **there is any alternate gearman call type(other than 'select') or is there any way to write update query that doesn't affect any mysql table/column?** Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post how you defined `gman_do_background`. It seems to be a *function*.

Comment: Hi Ravinder, its provided by gearman(as you can see on the link). The documentation is here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16060416/README.txt . yes, that is declared as a mysql function.

Comment: Is the `select ...` being used in a *trigger* body? If yes, they can't be action *terminating* statements, but only as cursors to use within the body.

Comment: yes, as I mentioned on the post, the gearman library mentions to use it as 'SELECT ...' . And can't see a way to change it. So, as I said in the second option, is there any way to create a fake UPDATE statement that really won't cause any real update?

Comment: Unless you post what your trigger body is like, none can advise.

Comment: Actually its very simple trigger. Its just select few things from a table and send to gearman server. I just updated the post with sample of the trigger.

Comment: Your query seems a bit strange. Do you select more than one row from mytable?

Answer (score 2):

**First of all** doing any non-transactional operations in a trigger are wrong. In case of a rollback you won't be able to undo calls to your udf function. So I'd suggest reconsider using triggers for this type of calls.

Highly recommended reading:

- [The Trouble with Triggers](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2008/08-sep/o58asktom-101055.html)

---

Now as you figured out `SELECT`s on their own are prohibited in triggers since there is no client to return the resultset to.

But you can legitimately use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM ...` syntax. You can create an auxiliary  table with `BLACKHOLE` engine if it is enabled in your MySQL instance. Anything you write to blackhole goes to /dev/null.

```sql
CREATE TABLE dev_null
(
  value VARCHAR(255) -- adjust data type as needed
) ENGINE=BLACKHOLE;
```

Then in your trigger

```sql
INSERT INTO dev_null
SELECT gman_do_background('eventName', @data) 
  FROM 
(
  ...
)
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1d98e/1)** demo

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this link http://codesamplez.com/development/gearman-from-mysql-udf helps (tip 2)